# SPSS - adding variable values across cases

Tags: spss

I have a variable for "purchase cost" for each case, but I want the total cohort purchase cost (i.e. purchase cost for case 1 + purchase cost for case 2 +...+ purchase cost for case X) combined into a single number.

Is there a specific command to do so in SPSS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can calculate the sum of purchase costs across all cases this way:

```
means purchase_cost/cells = sum.
```

The sum will appear in the output window.

If, instead, you would like to add a variable to the present dataset, containing the sum of purchase cost, use the `aggregate` function:

```
AGGREGATE
  /OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES
  /BREAK=
  /PC_sum=SUM(purchase_cost).
```

Finally, if you want a cumulative sum of purchase costs, so that each case contains the sum of purchase costs of all the cases above, use the `create csum` command:

```
create PC_sum=CSUM(purchase_cost).
```

Comment: Thanks so much eli-k!